# Insert string behind consecutive numbers in string?

Tags: c#, string, unity-game-engine, logic, unityscript

I'm using Unity and an answer in UnityScript especially or C# would help. I'm making a calculator using `eval()` and I need exponents using `^`

I want to take:

```
1+2^
```

and replace `^` with `,` and insert `Mathf.Pow(` behind `2`.

**I need it to work even when "2" has more than one digit.**

It needs to become:

```
1+Mathf.Pow(2, 
//Mathf.Pow is exponents using 2 parameters
```

Now, when user types `3`, it becomes `1+Mathf.Pow(2,3`. I already know how to add `)` when user types a non-number.

Comment: can you simplify the issue a bit more

Comment: @user2320445 i'd like to take "abc123^456" and change it into "abc(123,456)". I need it to also work for something like "gh1473209^2" and make it "gh(1473209,2)"

Answer (score 2):

Just **Replace** and **Insert** is enough.

```
function Start () 
{    
var s : String = "1+1245^6+3";
var MathString : String = "Mathf.Pow(";
var MathString1 : String = ")";
var strResult : String  = "";
var j : int;
s = s.Replace('^', '.');

for( var i=0; i< s.length; i++)
{
  if(s[i]=='+' || s[i]=='-' || s[i]=='/')   
    j=i;        
  if(s[i]=='.')
  {
     strResult = s.Insert((i+2), MathString1 );
     s= strResult;
     print(j);
     strResult = s.Insert((j+1), MathString );
  } 
 }
 print(strResult);// 1+Mathf.Pow(1245.6)+3
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite answer my problem. I need it to work even when the number before "^" has more than one digit. If I have 1+10^2+3 it would become 1+1Mathf.Pow(0,2)+3

Comment: This does actually help. Instead of MathString being inserted in i-1, I can repetitively test if each character is a number and return how many numbers there are. I can insert MathString in the slot i-[how ever many numbers there are consecutively before ^] I still can't get it exactly though

Comment: Now check my Answer Edited based on your need